# Irreducible factors of x^16 - 1 over GF(3)

Tags: combinatorics, factoring, irreducible-polynomials, coding-theory

Just want to double check my work. I'm trying to list the irreducible factors of $x^{16} − 1 $ over $GF (3)$ of degree $1$ and $2$ . Here's what I have:

$$x + 1, x + 2, x^2 + x + 2, x^2 + 2x + 2$$

Is that all of them?

Comment: Why don't you **first** show us the factorization of the polynomial?!

Comment: The list is incomplete.

Comment: When i factored I got this: (x+1) (x+2) (x^2+1) (x^2+x+2) (x^2+2 x+2) (x^4+x^2+2) (x^4+2 x^2+2)

Answer (score 5):

Not quite:
$$
x^{16}-1=(x^8-1)(x^8+1)=(x^4-1)(x^4+1)(x^8+1).
$$
You correctly factored
$$
x^4+1=x^4+4=(x^4+4x^2+4)-4x^2=(x^2+2)^2-(2x)^2=(x^2-2x+2)(x^2+2x+2),
$$
but you haven't fully factored $x^4-1$ yet.

The remaining factors are those of $x^8+1$. By repeating the above trick you can write it as a product of two quartics. Those quartics are irreducible though. This is because if $\alpha$ is a zero of $x^8+1$ in some extension field of $GF(3)$, then $\alpha$ is of order $16$. This means that $\alpha\in GF(81)\setminus GF(9)$. Consequently its minimal polynomial is of degree four.

Comment: When I factored I got this: GF(3): (x+1) (x+2) (x^2+1) (x^2+x+2) (x^2+2 x+2) (x^4+x^2+2) (x^4+2 x^2+2). Is this not correct?

Comment: That is correct, @Nelson. The quadratic factor $x^2+1$ was missing from the list in the original version of your post, which is what all this has been about :-) +1 to your post has been there for a while.

Comment: Thanks, but x^2 + 1 isn't irreducible is it?

Comment: Sure it is! It has no zeros in $GF(3)$, so no linear factors, and thus it is irreducible. It would not be irreducible in $GF(2)$ of $GF(5)$, but it is in $GF(3)$.

Comment: Wow, I definitely knew that! My bad. Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: One more question, if i have to name the degrees of the irreducible factors, would that be 1, 2, and 4?

Comment: I would prefer to list them as $1,1,2,2,2,4,4$, but your teacher may disagree (IMO it is pointless to ask for that - students can be relied upon to correctly determine the degree of a polynomial written out).

Answer (score 2):

Since 
$$ x^{16}-1 = \Phi_{16}(x)\,\Phi_{8}(x)\,\Phi_4(x)\,\Phi_2(x)(x-1) $$
and $\Phi_{16}(x)$ completely splits over $\mathbb{F}_{3^4}$ since $16|(3^4-1)$,  $\Phi_8(x)$ completely splits over $\mathbb{F}_{3^2}$ since $8|(3^2-1)$ and $\Phi_4(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_3$, we have that $x^{16}-1$ splits as a product of two quartic irreducible polynomials, three quadratic irreducible polynomials and two linear factors.

Answer (score 0):

You missed one.

In Maple:

```
select(t -> degree(t) <= 2, Factor(x^16-1) mod 3);
```